# How to turn char a into b in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, char, increment

Hi i am trying to increment a char in vb.net, eg:
Dim letter As Char = "a"c. and i want to make it b, and so on. how can i do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could get the ascii code, increment, and convert back to Char:

```
Chr(Asc(letter) + 1)
```

The Unicode version of this is:

```
ChrW(AscW(letter) + 1)
```

EDIT:

As Glen pointed out, you need to be careful if you are trying to increment "z"c

Comment: just watch out for incrementing "z". Ascii "z" + 1 = "{".

Comment: thank you. had to use Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW((Asc(letter) + 1)) though.